# How to add class to table row in JQuery and save it after reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I use jquery to highlight the selected row in bootstrap table. The problem is that after reloading the page the highlight disappears. Is it possible to save it after reloading as well?

The selected objectName is saving in global variable. Maybe I can use it somehow.

**js page:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.name-row', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('bg-info text-light').siblings().removeClass('bg-info text-light');
    selectedName = $(this).find("#object-name-column").text();
});
```

**html page:**

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var selectedName;
        /*]]>*/
    </script>



<table class="table table-hover" id="my-table" style="cursor:pointer">
     <thead>
           <tr>

               <th scope="col">Name</th>
               <th scope="col">Date</th>

          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
               <tr class="name-row" th:each="object:${objects}"
                  <td id="object-name-column" th:text="${object.name}"></td>
                  <td id="date-column"> th:text="${object.date}"></td>
               </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by saving some information about the last selected column either in your db, browser's local storage or some other storage

To do this with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

Set a reference whenever user clicks a column

```
$('body').on('click', '.name-row', function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('bg-info text-light').siblings().removeClass('bg-info text-light');
    selectedName = $(this).find("#object-name-column").text();

    // store selected column for future reference
    localStorage.setItem("selectedName", selectedName);
});
```

Retrieve previously selected column

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var prevSelected = localStorage.getItem("selectedName")
   // check if prevSelected is !undefined else do whatever you wish with selected column
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible through local storage. Once your class added to table row, save it in local storage, and from next time you can call that class from local storage.